# Output depending of 2 sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a "calculator" just with 2 variables as input slider:

Slider X and Slider Y.

So when you move, X (3 values) you have in Y (3 values each X value, total 9 values).

In codepen i watch a lot of calculators, but the issue is the "step" is always linear.

I need 3 values like, 80 70 and 200.

thats so close:

https://codepen.io/neel2292/pen/jbjMLe

But i want something like, you choose a value in X and a value in Y so you have 1 output.

In total you have 9 diferent outputs X (3) and Y (9, 3 each X)

Its possible make something like this, but with 2 slider?:

```
$( function() {
            var p = {       
                0: "3 months",
                1: "6 months",
                2: "12 months",
            };

                var t = {
                0: "2.083,33 €/month",
                1: "1.041,67 €/month",
                2: "520,83 €/month",
            };

            $("#slider").slider({
               value: "1",
                min: 0,
                max: 2,
                step: 1,
                slide: function(event, ui) {

                    $("#price").val(t[ui.value]);
                    $("#amount").val(p[ui.value]);  
                }
            });
});
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. And you could have a table to store the 9 reults first, for example: `resultArray=[{"p":0, "t":0, "cost":"6.249,99€"},{"p":0, "t":1, "cost":"3.125,01€"}...]`

Comment: Oh! Yes, can you link me a example in codepen? Would be great. Or can u tell me how can i search it? Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**
You could use oninput to replace on change.

codepen:
https://codepen.io/kuiexbpq/pen/BaNqmMe?editors=1111

And if you want to use jQuery Slider Widget 
`$('#slideElement').slider({})`, I think it is ok, you could try.

Try this:

Javascript:

```
var getResult = function() {
    var tokenP = $('#price_slider').val();
    var tokenT = $('#months_slider').val();
    var pLable = ["1000 USD","1500 USD", "2000 USD"];
    var tLable = ["1 month", "1.5months", "2.5 months"];

    var resultArray=[{"p":"0","t":"0","cost":"1000"},   {"p":"0","t":"1","cost":"1640"},{"p":"0","t":"2","cost":"5000"},{"p":"1","t":"0","cost":"1800"},{"p":"1","t":"1","cost":"3000"},{"p":"1","t":"2","cost":"2000"},{"p":"2","t":"0","cost":"8000"},{"p":"2","t":"1","cost":"7000"},{"p":"2","t":"2","cost":""Give U a Special Discount 1450!"}];
    var output="";
    resultArray.forEach(result=>{
        if(result.p === tokenP && result.t === tokenT)
        {
            output = result.cost
        }
    })
    $('.installment-value').text(output);
    $('#price_value').text(pLable[Number(tokenP)]);
    $('#months_value').text(tLable[Number(tokenT)]);
}


$('#price_slider').change(function(event) {
    getResult();
});

$('#months_slider').change(function(event) {
    getResult();
});
```

CodePen:
https://codepen.io/kuiexbpq/pen/BaNqmMe?editors=1111

Comment: Oh its brilliant. Its possible live change while i move the slider?

Comment: With ".slider" instead ".change" the data change while you move the slider. Its possible introduce ".slider" instead ".change"?